# Rx-Java2 Floawable.rebatchRequests doesn't rebatch requests

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Consider the following usercase:

```
Iterable<Object> it = getATerabyteOfDataOnDemand();
Flowable.fromIterable(it)
    .blockingSubscribe(v -> consumeSlowly(v));
```

The expected result when I execute the prior code is I should get an out of memory exception, as Flowable.blockingSubscribe requests Long.MAX_VALUE items, the iterator is drained of a terabyte of data, and the subscriber is unable to keep up.

---

To resolve this, I add the rebatchRequests to my code:

```
Iterable<Object> it = getATerabyteOfDataOnDemand();
Flowable.fromIterable(it)
    .rebatchRequests(128)
    .blockingSubscribe(v -> consumeSlowly(v));
```

My expected result when I execute the following code is that everything works perfectly, as the documentation for [Flowable.rebatchRequests](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#rebatchRequests-int-) states that:

> This operator allows preventing the downstream to trigger unbounded mode via request(Long.MAX_VALUE) or compensate for the per-item overhead of small and frequent requests.

In practice, I get another out-of-memory exception.  How to I use backpressure to prevent the flowable from draining the iterator immediately?

Comment: Creating a custom subscriber that requests a single item at a time prevents the out of memory exception, but I'd like to know why rebatchRequests isn't working as described.

Comment: Also, I understand that this is a synchronous flow, but I'm looking for a way to rebatch requests that works with both synchronous and asynchronous flows. When adding `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` to the chain, a few items are consumed, but I still run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a synchronous flow and `blockingSubscribe` queues up items which then can't be consumed due to `fromIterable` still emitting on the same thread. `rebatchRequest` doesn't help here because its consumer is still the unbounded `blockingSubscribe` so it always takes items and consumes `fromIterable` fully.

Either you don't need `blockingSubscribe` or you should consider using `blockingIterable()` with for-each which requests more only when the current thread has actually consumed items. Otherwise, you'll have to use the `blockingSubscribe(Subscriber)` overload and request manually:

```java
source.blockingSubscribe(new Subscriber<T>() {
    Subscription upstream;
    @Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        upstream = s;
        s.request(1);
    }

    @Override public void onNext(T item) {
        consumeSlowly(v);
        upstream.request(1);
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override public void onComplete() {
    }
});
```

Note however that you already have an `Iterable` which you can consume synchronously with for-each without RxJava's involvement.

Comment: See my comment, I understand it works with a custom subscriber, I want to know how to rebatch requests so it will work with any subscriber

Comment: You can't. It is that `blockingSubscribe` overload what's the problem. It will keep queueing indefinitely and never start consuming that queue because they are on the same thread.

Comment: In the particular scenario, you don't even need RxJava as `Iterable` will have the necessary backpressure as you can only move one item forward via `Iterator.next()` at a time.